# Geocoding is running after my page loads

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, geocoding

I am trying to build a map using information from an API. Unfortunately the dataset does not have coordinates. So i am using the address and Geocoding them to build a google map with markers and get the distance along with directions from current location. I takes the user's current location and finds the requested information with a 10 mile radius around them.

Here is my Geocoding function

```
<script>
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, street, city, zip) {
    var address = street + ', ' + city + ', ' + zip;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        debugger;
        return(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Here is the loop that scans through all the data from the API call

```
$my_counter = 0;
foreach ($param as &$value){
$row = $value;
echo" 
    <script>
    //the return information is messy so i use this to clean it up
    var coordinates = geocodeAddress(geocoder, '".trim(str_replace(',', '',$row->address))."', '".trim($row->city)."', '".trim($row->zip)."');
    console.log(coordinates);
    var new_lat = parseFloat(coordinates[0]);
    var new_long = parseFloat(coordinates[1]);
    var distance_to_the_point = haversineGreatCircleDistance (".$original_gps_lat.", ".$original_gps_long.", new_lat, new_long);
    if (distance_to_the_point <= ".$radius."){
        var data = '".$row->phone."';
        var result = data;
        var rounded_distance = distance_to_the_point.toFixed(2);
        var name = '".trim($row->provider_name)."';
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name.toString();
        }
        ";
    </script>
```

Now when i run this with break points and logs throughout, I see the geocoding function running, but never giving a return. Then once the page has loaded, the geocoder finishes and i see the returned coordinates. i do not understand why it's not running in sync.

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous.  You can't return anything from an asynchronous callback function.

Answer (score -1):

Because the second parameter to `geocoder.geocode()` is a `function` that is an asynchronous callback.  That's a very common pattern in Javascript, so you'll need to embrace it and not start trying to call geocode until the page is loaded, such as with jquery's [ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Here is some good reading on callbacks: [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch2.md)

Comment: Another way to embrace asynchronous programming in javascript is using babel (server side, with something like gulp/grunt) so you can use ES6/JS 2015 features like async/await.  [YDKJS Chapter 8](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/0e3b97b5928a9d9a91ad08e5c209e43644dc9deb/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch8.md)

Comment: Downvotes with no comments are not useful, how can anyone learn from that?